# Need advice with with a choice of layout

Tags: android, layout

I need to set views into some layout. View will be one by one by one like in `LinearLayout` with  `orientational="horizontal"` and if there is no place then last view will go to the next line. How it possible?

---

```
Small screen    Bigger screen
| [][][] |      | [][][][] |
| [][][] |  ->  | [][][][] |
| [][][] |      | []       |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) is the way to go. It'll give you two-dimensional scrollable grid and you can make it choose the number of columns automatically by stating that `numColumns` parameter equals to `auto_fit`.

Answer (score 0):

Use WeightSum attribute in the layout & layout_Weight in the views

[Check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696920/android-layout-layoutweight-and-weightsum?answertab=oldest#tab-top) for reference

Comment: I think that it's not that I want.