# CalendarView not displaying all days in month for some smaller screen size

Tags: android, android-layout, google-calendar-api, android-xml, android-calendar

Here is my calendar view

```
<CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendarView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

Below this I have 3 buttons with the below given xml

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:padding="5dp" android:stretchColumns="0"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/trackAttendance"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Track Class Attendance"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/mybuttons"> </Button>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/trackSessions"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Track Study Sessions"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/mybuttons"> </Button>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/trackActivities"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Track Class Activities"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/mybuttons"> </Button>
        </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

I am unable to view all the days for month in the calendar view when i run it on some phones with screen size less than 4.5". It is displayed as shown below

[image]

Is there any work around for this without using **stock google** calendarview.
Thanks in advance

Comment: github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview

Comment: Try this javatechig.com/android/custom-calendar-view-library-in-android

Comment: @NiravRanpara is there any way to achieve it via stock view

Comment: not sure about this. I recommend to use github lib

Comment: Have you tried adding scrollview ? and putting those buttons in one seperate layout container and giving marginTop.

Comment: Why don't you just enable scrolling? setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(boolean verticalScrollBarEnabled)

Comment: Or - put it in Linear layout with weights

Comment: @ShreeKrishna that solution didnt work

Comment: @Android_developer setVerticalScrollBarEnabled didnt work and linear weight can you give me a sample code.

Comment: Did you try putting your entire view in ScrollView and use Relative Layout. (using layout_below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Happening Because heights of your Buttons are `wrap_content`..

So Buttons overlapping Your Calendar View

Either Try creating Layout Using `ScrollView` Refer [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674341/how-to-use-scrollview-in-android) .

or

Use `LinearLayout` with `weightsum` and `layout_Weight`.  Refer [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696920/android-layout-layoutweight-and-weightsum) .