# Layout Elements Covering corners

Tags: android, xml, absolutelayout

I am using AbsoluteLayout to try and cover the entire screen with the elements I want to add to create a "FullScreen" menu but it does not cover it. this is what I get. let me share my code as well , as youu see the Pink panel does not cover the corner of the screen why is that? 
[image]

MainActivity xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.apos.champquess.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="77dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="404dp"
    android:layout_height="550dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button"
    android:src="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:layout_x="280dp"
    android:layout_y="78dp" />

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New RadioButton"
    android:id="@+id/radioButton"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="231dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="231dp"
    android:layout_x="150dp"
    android:layout_y="73dp" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New CheckBox"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_x="710dp"
    android:layout_y="238dp" />
```

And MainActity Java

```
package com.example.apos.champquess;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Remove title bar
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        //Remove notification bar
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        //set content view AFTER ABOVE sequence (to avoid crash)
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

EDIT: This is what I want it to look like (example)

[image]

Comment: "Pink panel does not cover the corner of the screen " can you explain a bit what actually you need to do? maybe with a sketch diagram

Comment: Hey @CharukaSilva I have added a screenshot of the desired effect at the bottom of the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quick answer here;

you use `AbsoluteLayout`
This class was **deprecated** in API level 3.
Use `FrameLayout`, `RelativeLayout` or a custom layout instead.

just take `RelativeLayout` as an example

`ImageView` is inside it and you have given width and height for it to possition it relatively

```
 android:layout_width="404dp"
 android:layout_height="550dp"
```

so it takes the size of that dimentions that's the reason it goes away the boundaries 
 + you have padding s in your root tag  `AbsoluteLayout`
 if you want to give sizes manually give a small width like `75 dp`

there are couple of ways do you task

but first do not try to give sizes *manually* then it will display *differently in different screen sizes* , but for a single screen you can give these values.
otherwise you need to use a value based on ratio. learn about `layout_weight` and `

> [What does android:layout_weight mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean)

`  and how to use it, a simple example -->[Android Layout - layoutweight and weightsum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696920/android-layout-layoutweight-and-weightsum)
or pragmatically you can give sizes based on ratio

```
// get screen sises 
     Display display = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            int screenY = size.y;
            int screenX = size.x; 

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams yourView= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(screenX, 270 * screenY / 1920);
        yourView.topMargin = 0;
        yourView.leftMargin = 125 * screenX / 1080;
        imgPoints.setLayoutParams(yourView);
```

and learn about `RelativeLayout` and `LinearLayout` behaviors as well

Comment: So this works like css ? should I go around using the layouts with the same logic ?

Comment: @ Demeteor try it out ur self and if you find it hard or if there is any issue leave a comment below so i can help you out