# Move View to "next line" if it doesn't fit

Tags: android, android-layout

So, idea in this: I have two `TextViews`, first can expand whatever it wants, second always 5 chars (time). Problem is in that first `TextView` can easily push second out of the screen.

So, what I need is something like adjustable `LinearLayout`, or maybe some `GridLayout` that will move second `TextView` on some sort of second line if it doesn't fit parent.

For example you can watch at message bubbles in Viber and WhatsApp. Thanks for any advise.

### Update 1

Here is XML that i have now (Only message part)

```
              <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/messageBox"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:gravity="center_vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:text='@{mess.message}'/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|end"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                    android:text='@{Utils.parseMillsToHoursAndMins(mess.date)}'/>
            </LinearLayout>
```

### Update 2

So I added layout_weight to first `TextView`, that helped with my first problem, but now I have new one. This two `TextView`s are in `LinearLayout` which is in another `LinearLayout` with another `TextView`. Parent `LinearLayout` have width set to wrap_content so if top `TextView` will be bigger than 2 `TextView`s it will cause child `LinearLayout` to be less than it's parent, and 2nd `TextView` (from that 2) wouldn't be in the end of parent. But when child `LinearLayout` is bigger, all appears to be OK. I know it's complicated, so this is XML

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/contentPanel"
            app:bringToFront="@{true}"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@{(mess.isMine?@drawable/chat_bubble_right:@drawable/chat_bubble_left)}">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text='@{!mess.authorRole.equals("Client")?(mess.authorRole + " - " + mess.author):mess.author}'
                android:textColor='@{mess.authorRole.equals("Lawyer")?@color/colorPrimary:mess.authorRole.equals("Admin")?@color/red:@color/green}'
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:id="@+id/author"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/messageBox">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="0.7"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:text='@{mess.message}'/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:gravity="bottom|end"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                    app:checkFit="@{false}"
                    android:text='@{Utils.parseMillsToHoursAndMins(mess.date)}'/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: put code here, so it will be easy

Comment: https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

Comment: Did you have a look at `weight` with `LinearLayout`?

Comment: show you xml code

Comment: @DavidMedenjak now I set weight of first view to 0.7 and something starts to be ok. But In this case second view is not in the end of parent view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure this will help you or not but: 
Use: https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout

```
<org.apmem.tools.layouts.FlowLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</org.apmem.tools.layouts.FlowLayout>
```

Inside FlowLayout you can put your view's and it will auto move to next line if not fit.

Comment: That's almost that I wanted! Maybe you know how to make second `TextView` in it align right side of view, if it was moved to next line?

Comment: I am not sure about that, but definitely it will auto fit in a row if space is available otherwise it will moves to the next line.

Comment: Yes, it moves second View in next row, but it appears to be in the beginning of the row, when I want it to be in the end. Setting second View layout_width to match_parent doesn't help.

Comment: What is second view? I mean if second view is Relative layout and inside this layout you put text view. In that case you can set relative layout width as match_parent and text view inside this layout set width wrap_content with android:layout_alignParentRight="true" to text view. Hope it will work for you. Its just idea, you can try with different point of views.

Comment: One more solution in library itself:
To change layout direction use the following code

xmlns:f="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/your.namespace"
f:layoutDirection="rtl"

Comment: No, layoutDirection and android:layout_alignParentRight didn't help.

Answer (score 4):

The new approach for achieving such behaviour is using ConstraintLayout with [Flow](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/helper/widget/Flow). Here is an example of usage:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
                        android:id="@+id/socialsButtonsFlow"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                        app:flow_horizontalGap="8dp"
                        app:flow_verticalGap="4dp"
                        app:flow_wrapMode="aligned"
                        app:flow_horizontalStyle="spread_inside"
                        app:constraint_referenced_ids="vkButton,twitterButton,facebookButton,youtubeButton,instagramButton,odnoklassnikiButton,tiktokButton"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/socialsLabel"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/socialsLabel"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/socialsLabel" />
```

For small screens it looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if your textviews in linearlayout you can add weightSum method

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696920/android-layout-layoutweight-and-weightsum